# Jupyter Notebook Import Error: cannot import name 'np_version_under1p17' from 'pandas.compat.numpy'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.dates as md
import datetime as dt
import time
from zipfile import ZipFile 
from matplotlib.pyplot import xticks

%matplotlib inline
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 1 import numpy as np
> ----> 2 import pandas as pd
> 3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
> 4 import seaborn as sns
> 5 import matplotlib.dates as md
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_*init*_.py in 
> 20
> 21 # numpy compat
> ---> 22 from pandas.compat.numpy import (
> 23     np_version_under1p17 as _np_version_under1p17,
> 24     np_version_under1p18 as _np_version_under1p18,
>
> **ImportError: cannot import name 'np_version_under1p17' from
> 'pandas.compat.numpy' (C:\Users\XX\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\numpy_*init*_.py)**

I have upgraded all conda libraries, uninstalled/installed pandas again, but its still stuck

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem and I think that there is no "*one-step*" solution.
For me, I recently installed python 64-bit version as I was using the 32-bit version till then. But due to some reason the new version was installed in a different location.
My problem was actually with the notebook. So I deleted all the files(the folder in which the old 32-bit python was installed) in the old path and reinstalled the notebook using `pip install notebook` and everything worked fine.

Before that try upgrading the current pandas version using `pip3 --upgrade pandas`. For me the problem was messed up installation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete ".ipynb_checkpoints" folder in folder with your *.ipynb file. Its helped me. Install and reinstall pandas didn't help me.